# Enable Stack Snippets on UX

Tags: feature-request, design

Stack Snippets are an awesome tool for demonstrating HTML/CSS/JS problems and solutions, and are easier than outsourcing to JS Fiddle. They're widely used on Stack Overflow. However, this site does not run Stack Snippets (even if you create them on Stack Overflow and copy the markup over here).

Stack Snippets would sometimes be useful on this site. (Example: [Hyperlink on red background](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/125341/2131).)

Can we have them enabled on UX SE?

Comment: One might argue that HTML/CSS/JS problems are off-topic on UX.SE anyway, the markup is not important. They might help to provide an interactive demo, but only the result view counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would encourage too many off-topic questions, or encourage users to answer in a more implementation-driven way.

For example:

> Q: When should I tell the user their password is about to expire?
>
> A: *You can wire it up via jQuery to pop up a Bootstrap modal after they click login. You just need to have an API call that tells you the expiry date. See my example below...*

There's only a couple times I've wanted the snippet available when answering, and each time I found the built-in mockup tool to be sufficient in conveying my suggestions.